# Как лучше? Локализация контента (только 2 языка). Laravel. Подскажите в общих фразах

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, оптимизация, локализация

Как лучше сделать локализацию бд? Сайт на Laravel.

Мои варианты:

1) использовать языковые файлы и в бд заносить ключи. Во вью отображать соответственно `{{__($categories->continent)}}`

2) сделать дубль всех таблиц с префиксом второго языка. В контроллерах делать как-то так:

```
`if(Config::get('app.locale') == 'ru') {
            $categories = DB::table('categories')......
        }
        else {
            $categories = DB::table('en_categories')......
        }`
```

Суть вопроса. Как правильней и лучше в плане скорости? Чтоб не давать лишнюю нагрузку. Сайт маленький. Удобство администрирования не имеет значения, я сам и админ, добавляю контент просто в бд, так что мне без особой разницы ключ туда писать, или же сам текст.

Comment: Зачем в бд заносить ключи? [Laravel localization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization) ведь зачем-то придумали

Comment: @InDevX это видел, там, как я понял, про локаль статичного текста. Это уже сделал. А как быть с контентом из бд?

у меня есть вью, там {{$products->country}} - с бд. 

чтоб использовать локал файлы, нужна запись типа 

{{__('product.country_b')}}

файл: /lang/en product.php содержит 'country_b' => 'Brasil', 'country_s' => 'Slovenia',

Соответственно, в бд для разных товаров разные ключи,  product.country_b, product.country_s 

Или я все неправильно понимаю?

Comment: Вполне можно без if/else это сделать так как у вас уже есть переменная текущей локали. Смотрите https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable как пример для Eloquent моделей и шаблоны многоязычности в https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/laravel-i18n-modelling-best-practices/